# Pyspark sqlContext execute sub query error with LIMIT

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I get the error:

> AnalysisException: u'Correlated scalar subqueries must be Aggregated: GlobalLimit 1\n+- LocalLimit 1\n   +- Aggregate [email#967], [max(lastdateupdate#189) AS max(lastdateupdate) ...

Working with SQL in a TempTable based on a dataframe.

```
df.registerTempTable('test')
```

This queries worked:

```
sqlContext.sql('select * from test t where lastdateupdate=(select max(lastdateupdate) from test u limit 1)')
```

But whit this, I get the error message:

```
sqlContext.sql('select * from test t where lastdateupdate=(select max(lastdateupdate) from test u where u.email=t.email limit 1)')
```

I don't understand why.